# Make DIV to the page bottom so that it does not stay on top of absolutely positioned content?

Tags: html, css

I have to add a wrapper around HTML content produced by others. What I want to achieve is to add a header and footer to all the pages (height varies) produced by other people so that all new pages have a header and footer. All the pages produced by others are absolutely positioned. How can I use CSS to make my footer stay in the bottom of pages, not on top of content produced by other people?

This is the HTML structure I have. I cannot change the HTML structure or CSS of the content produced by others.

```
<div class="my-wrapper">
  <div class="my-header">my header </div>
  <div class="others-wrapper">
     <div class="html-from-other-people">
       <div> <!--this is one outside container -->
        A few outside container DIVs and then comes the absolutely-positioned DIV with content.
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-footer">footer goes here</div> 
</div>
```

I cannot have sticky header or footer. The footer has to stay in the bottom of page content, not the bottom of the viewport.

**UPDATE**

The HTML from other people is structured with a few outside container DIVs and then the absolutely-positioned DIV with content. Please see the updated example HTML above.

Comment: **1**- can you change the `top` position of the content? **2**- can you change the `position:absolute` property?

Comment: @freestock.tk. Suppose, I can change these. What is your solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:flex` could do the job:

```css
html,
body,
.my-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.my-wrapper {
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  background:tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.others-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background:turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-wrapper">
  <div class="my-header">my header , <br/>never mind the size</div>
  <div class="others-wrapper">
    <div class="html-from-other-people">use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-footer">footer goes here never mind the size</div>
</div>
```

---

version without sticky header / footer

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.my-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  background:tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.others-wrapper {
  flex:1 ;
  background:turquoise;
}
/* demo purpose */

.others-wrapper {
  color:green;
  font-size:1.5em;
}

.html-from-other-people {
  color:black;
  font-size:0.75em
}
:checked + div {
  font-size:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="my-wrapper">
  <div class="my-header">my header , <br/>never mind the size</div>
  <div class="others-wrapper">QUICK DEMO PURPOSE show/hide text below:<input type="checkbox">
    <div class="html-from-other-people">
        use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed <br/>use whole space between header & footer and scrlls if needed 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-footer">footer goes here never mind the size</div>
</div>
```

Comment: GCyrillus, thanks for helping me! What I need to have is to have the footer in the content's bottom. Having sticky header and footer is not that I want. Sorry for being unclear. Thanks for help!

Comment: @curious1 then height to wrapper can be removed or turned to min-height and overflow remove too . flex:1 comes an option if you want to push footer down the screen, else remove it too..See updated answer) Html structure is yours, footer stands out others . I just do not understand this absolute positionning wich is not needed in my own humble opinion :)

Comment: I am not able to see  how others' content is absolutely positioned in your CSS.

Comment: @curious1 there is none, my question was: Why should you use it unless to will to have a layout that can break anytime  ?

Comment: I am not able to control the html from other people. Their content is absolutely positioned, which I cannot change. I simply need to add wrapper (header and footer) around it. In your code, I am not able to see how your html and css 100% reflects the problem I have.

Comment: @curious1 ?? if content is inside same page (and not via a frame), you can reset the absolute position. For me, i believe that at that point i have not  enough relevant info to see what really goes on, to propose an efficient answer or advise at this point. sorry :)

Comment: I updated my post to reflect the structure of the HTML from other people.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can handle it keeping the `position:absolute`: Javascript calculates the header size then places the content after it using `top`. Then, increases the body size to open up space and does the same on the content placing the footer after it with `top`. The function runs on body load because it needs a loaded content to gets the proper size.

*Alternatively, if you're able to let content's position other than 'absolute', you can use `document.getElementById("Id").appendChild(element);` to place the sections easier (since you don't need to wait the contents load to pick up their size).*

```js
function rebuild(){
var contentheight = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
var bodyheight = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].offsetHeight;
var headerheight = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
var footerheight = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;

var result1 = bodyheight + footerheight;
var result2 = contentheight + headerheight;

document.getElementById("content").style.top = headerheight;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.height = result1 + "px";
document.getElementById("footer").style.top = result2 + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

#header {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background: skyblue;
}

#content {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width:100%;
background: gold;
}

#footer {
position: absolute;
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rebuild()">

<div id=header>header</div>

<div id=content> text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>

<div id=footer>footer content<br>footer content<br>footer content<br></div>
```

Comment: freestock.tk: I feel a gut feel that your solution may work. But I am not able to see how you can have a block of content (many links and images) as the footer because you use only text "footer" as footer and display it via ':after'. Besides, what is the purpose of the block with #content2?

Comment: Sorry, tha #content2 is a mistake I was using it on tests but it wasnt supposed to be there anymore! I'm going to remove it, thanks for the warning;

Comment: I knew the previous method had limitations on the footer; anyway, its "fixed" with javascript now with no limits on footer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need the divs with the my-wrapper or html-from-other-people classes unless you are doing something special with them. You can just use the divs with my-header, others-wrapper, and my-footer classes. Give those classes some height of fill them with content.

I'm not sure how your users are adding their content but if you are using jQuery you can do it by using

```
var usersContent = assign user content;
$('.others-wrapper').append(usersContent);
```

Your header will always be at the top and your footer will be at the bottom of whatever the user adds in. I would not use absolute positioning because that would cause overlapping if the users content is set to be higher than the viewing area. Plus you can't be sure about the viewing area of the device of all your users. If you do it this way you will not need as much CSS and you let the device deal with the proper placement.

HTML looks like this.

```
<div class="my-header">my header </div>
<div class="others-wrapper">
</div>
<div class="my-footer">footer goes here</div>
```

Comment: andre, this might be the direction, but the problem is that my footer is, in terms HTML structure, not part of the absolutely positioned HTML from other after being appended. I tested your solution and it is not working for me. The absolute positioning in others' content starts inside a few other DIVs.

Comment: If you are in control of the CSS I would just remove absolute positioning. If the user is setting the CSS then I would advise against letting them do that. You could end up with many more problems than positioning.

Comment: andre, thanks for your input. Upvoted your input. Thanks!